# Show all build errors in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-build

When I build my app and it has a number of errors, it stops on the first class with errors.
Only when I fix that and restart the build do I get any other errors.

I can't seem to find how to get it to go through all the errors at once.

Am I missing something simple?